# Run my app in android studio, it Creates two copies of icon

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I run my app in Android Studio, It Created two copies of icon in android phone.

First icon starts with login page and second icon starts with opening a camera for scanning barcode.

How do i create only one icon in android phone?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkWa4.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have only one `Activity` declared in `AndroidManifest` with `intent-filter`  like bellow:

```
<intent-filter>
   ...
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: can i put <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> instead of <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />?

Comment: post you `AndroidManifest` if you could.

Answer (score 0):

To fully resolve this problem you would need to provide more information abut your project.

I will assume that you installed two instances of your app on your phone and don't realize why that happened. My guess is that you installed application to your Android phone/emulator, changed application id and then installed it again.

Android differentiates apps by their application id which is defined in your module's(usually called app) build.gradle file and will only overwrite apps with same application id.